# ExpressJS 4 non existing routes vs non existing methods on existing route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building an API on NodeJS using Express 4. I would like to provide a different response between routes that do not exist and HTTP methods which given route does not support.

Lets say I have only 1 route (in this example, '/existing') which supports both GET and POST methods.

```
app.route('/existing')
.get(function(req, res) {/**/})
.post(functtion(req, res) {/**/});
```

What I am looking for is to have different responses depending on if the request is:

1. Path: /existing, method: PUT
2. Path: /nonexisting, method: *any*

What I have now is a middleware at the end of my routing file, but treats both cases as the same.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.